# Ambiguous use of 'sd_setImage(with:placeholderImage:completed:)' with Swift 3

Tags: ios, sdwebimage, swift3, xcode8

I am making the following call using `SDWebImage` on my `imageView`, which works fine with `Swift 2` but gives an error with `XCode 8 beta 5` compiling with `Swift 3`:

```
 imageView.sd_setImage(with:url, placeholderImage:placeholder, completed: {
    (image: UIImage?, error: Error?, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: URL?) in
            ...
    });
```

The error is:

> Ambiguous use of 'sd_setImage(with:placeholderImage:completed:)'

I suspect I have something wrong in the signature for the completed handler, but I can't figure out what the syntax should be. What am I missing?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The Swift compiler translates the ObjC headers into Swift which leads to naming collisions:

#### UIImageView+WebCache.h:

```
o1) - (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock;

o2) - (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock;
```

Their only difference is the additional `options`parameter in *o2*.

#### Generated Swift declaration:

```
s1) open func sd_setImage(with url: URL!, placeholderImage placeholder: UIImage!, completed completedBlock: SDWebImage.SDWebImageCompletionBlock!)

s2) open func sd_setImage(with url: URL!, placeholderImage placeholder: UIImage!, options: SDWebImageOptions = [], completed completedBlock: SDWebImage.SDWebImageCompletionBlock!)
```

Because `options` was translated into an optional parameter (default assigned an empty array) calling *s1* in Swift leads to an ambiguous use. Calling *s2* could simply have the same implementation.
When providing such methods in Swift code one would add the `options` parameter as optional in a single function implementation.

### Workaround

As a workaround the `options` parameter could be set or *o1* or *o2* could be renamed temporarily until SDWebImage will be translated into Swift.

Comment: Good spot. Thank you. In addition here is the lien, that fixes temporary the collision issue: yourImageView.sd_setImage(with: yourUrl, placeholderImage: yourPlaceholderImage, options: SDWebImageOptions(), completed: yourImageTransitionCompletitionBlock)

Answer (score 19):

Adding `SDWebImageOptions` to the method call fixes the issue:

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: someUrl,
          placeholderImage: someImage,
                   options: [], 
                 completed: someCompletitionBlock)
```

Comment: I was using Swift inside objective-c project. Renaming stuff was not at all a option as previous Objective-C code was also using those methods. Your solution is perfect for my type of scenario