# Not able to use closure syntax in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8-beta4

I am trying to use closure Xcode8 beta4 with Swift3 , but it does not working. Same functions with closure working in Swift2.2, but it fails in Swift3.

**Swift 2.2**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

        self.viewForInstagramLoginWebView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y,self.viewForInstagramLoginWebView.frame.size.width , self.viewForInstagramLoginWebView.frame.size.height)

    }) { (finished) in

        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }
```

But same syntax not working with Swift3.

Also try by creating function with closure.

```
func greetingMessageWithDate(date : NSDate, message  :String, successHandler : (greetingMessage : String, code : Int ) -> Void){

}
```

Same function working in **Swift 2.2**, but not in **Swift 3**

Also facing issue with `SDWebImage` completion block.
I am able to use `SDWebImage` without completion handler, but with completion handler it fails.

Works without completion handler.

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "imageURL"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named : "imageName"))
```

But when using with completion handler, compiler complains with given message.

> Ambiguous use of 'sd_setImage(with:placeholderImage:completed:)'

[image]

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "imageName"), completed: { (image, error , cacheType , imageURL) in

        })
```

It looks like, change would be in closure syntax, but how to find that What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIView animation syntax changed in Swift 3 to:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

}, completion: { (Bool) in

})
```

Calling `greetingMessageWithDate`:

```
greetingMessageWithDate(date: Date(), message: "") { (greetingMessage: String, code: Int) in

}
```

Comment: Can you give me solution for `SDWebImage` ?

Comment: I guess it is not compatible to Swift 3 right now. The regular Swift 3 syntax is not working out of the box. There is also a on open issue regarding Swift 3 support: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/1627

Comment: Could you mark the answer as correct for the general usage of closures with Swift 3?

Comment: I am accepting answer for now, but expecting update for `SDWebImage`. Thanks

Comment: Regarding SDWebImage see this answer for a workaround and detailled explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39024894/2099148