# SDWebImage Library getting error with swift 3 Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, xcode8, sdwebimage

My Project was Developed with Xcode 7, Yesterday I have updated it with Xcode 8 and convert swift coding with latest swift version swift 3.0. Now it gives me error on some place all most I have solved all but not getting ID for ambiguous use of `sd_setImage(with: ,placeholderImage: ,completed)` line. can any one help me to solve this? I am using `SDWebimage` Library to load image in my application.

[image]

Thanks

Already checked this link but not getting what to do.
[Ambiguous use of 'sd_setImage(with:placeholderImage:completed:)' with Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949214/ambiguous-use-of-sd-setimagewithplaceholderimagecompleted-with-swift-3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous use of 'sd\_setImage(with:placeholderImage:completed:)' with Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949214/ambiguous-use-of-sd-setimagewithplaceholderimagecompleted-with-swift-3)

Comment: I have checked that but not getting exactly what I need to do so can you explain me that things in other words?

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 has a new way of interpreting Obj-C headers, seems like there are now 2 method signatures from 2 diff classes colliding.

A temporary fix could be using the url:placeholderImage:options:completed variant.

```
    view.sd_setImage(with: photoURL, placeholderImage: placeHolderImage, 
options: [.continueInBackground, .lowPriority]) { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think this will resolve your problem

```
YOURIMAGEVIEW.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: IMAGEURL), 
placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"PLACEHOLDER"), options: [], completed: { 
(image, error, cache, url) in
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      YOURIMAGEVIEW.image = image
   }
})
```

from that https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024894/4720374